# Is there any Python function to read Excel file with Date and Month not year?

Tags: python, excel, date

In an Excel sheet, the column with `Feb-16` internally taking as `01.02.2016`. How can I read the excel file in the same Month-Date format? Is there any function in Python I can use? After reading the file in Python, I am getting date only.

Excel File:

```
Year    MonthDate
2009    Feb-16
```

Code:

```
df_events = pd.read_excel('HolidaysData.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
Year  MonthDate
2009  2016-02-01
```

I am expected in Python code to output this:

```
Year  MonthDate
2009  02-16  OR Feb-16
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.dt.strftime("%m-%Y")`

```
df_events = pd.read_excel('HolidaysData.xlsx')
df_events["MonthDate"] = df.MonthDate.dt.strftime("%m-%Y")
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Edit: for two digit year use `%y`

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Now I got Monthdate field as 02-2016. Is there any way to cut down 2016 to only 16?

Comment: You can just use lowercase as in `"%m-%y"`

Comment: You are simply awesome Charles. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that helped @RavindraA -- if the problem is resolved you should mark this question as answered